# Vertical Scroll along with Horizontal Swipe in Android

Tags: android, touch, scrollview

I am trying for swiping in Android using OnGestureListener.I need  vertical Scrolling of text if it exceeds the layout height.I need Verical scroll and horizontal swipe should work together.The code is:

```
package com.example.gestures;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Gestures extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
GestureDetector gDetector;TextView tv;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestures);
        gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    }







    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gestures, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onDown","In OnDown");
        return true;

    }



    public void rightToLeft() {

        //tv.setText("There are subclasses of LayoutParams for different subclasses of ViewGroup. For example, AbsoluteLayout has its own subclass of LayoutParams which adds an X and Y value.");
    tv.setText("ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssALGIERS (Reuters) - Algerian President Abdelaziz Bouteflika, who suffered a stroke last year, has been in a Paris hospital since Monday for a long-planned check-up and he is making steady progress, the state news agency APS said on Tuesday.Algerians vote for a new president in April. Bouteflika, 76, has yet to announce whether he will run again after more than 10 years at the helm of the major North African oil producer.To complete his health assessment, started in Algiers, and under a routine medical control ... planned since June 2013, the President of the Republic Abdelaziz Bouteflika is staying at Val-de-Grace hospital, it said. The president's health is improving certainly and progressively.APS, citing a presidential statement, said Bouteflika would remain at the hospital until Friday.A veteran of Algeria's independence war against France, Bouteflika suffered a stroke in early 2013, forcing him to be rushed to hospital in France. He returned to Algeria in July to convalesce and has made only a few public appearances recently.");
    }
    public void lefttoRight() {
        tv.setText("leftToRight LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child view attributes that this class supports. ");
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        /*if(start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX())
        {
            Log.d("onFling","in inFling");
        }
        else if(start.getRawX()>finish.getRawX())
        {
            Log.d("onFLing","in onFling");
        }*/
        if (Math.abs(start.getY() - finish.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;
        // right to left swipe

        if(start.getX() - finish.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

        lefttoRight();

        }  
        else if (finish.getX() - start.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
     rightToLeft();
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onLongPress","in onlongpress");
    }



    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onShowPress","in onShowPress");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onSingleTapup","in onsingletapup");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
            float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the xml file(activity_gestures.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Gestures" >



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue is sometimes scroll is working and swipe is not working fine.Please let me know how to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom ScrollView by extending it and implement dispatchTouchEvent.

We start tracking the touch ( with the pixel positions on sceen ) in `ACTION_DOWN`. When we see that it's a horizontal swipe, we do not call `super.dispatchTouchEvent( event )` - which would do the default onTouch routing and make certain child views consume the horizontal swipe too - but call `onTouchEvent( event )` instead in `ACTION_MOVE` and also in `ACTION_UP`.

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private float mLastX;
    private float mLastY;
    private final int mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get( getContext() ).getScaledTouchSlop();
    private float mStartX;

    public ScrollView( Context context ) {
        super( context );
    }

    public ScrollView( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
    switch( event.getAction() ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastX = event.getX();
            mLastY = event.getY();
            mStartX = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            onTouchEvent( event );
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            float xDelta = x - mLastX;
            float xDeltaAbs = Math.abs( xDelta );
            float yDeltaAbs = Math.abs( y - mLastY );

            float xDeltaTotal = x - mStartX;
            if( Math.abs( xDeltaTotal ) > mTouchSlop )
                if( xDeltaAbs > yDeltaAbs )
                    return onTouchEvent( event );
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
    }
}
```

I only tried this with ViewPager instead of a ScrollVIew, but in this same situation so this should work